# .NET ClickOnce Deployment On XP through File Share

Tags: c#, .net, networking, setup-deployment

I got a specific question about ClickOnce Deployment on .net. Here is the thing I got an windows application which powered .net framework 3.5 C#. The purpose for ClickOnce is auto update. We have a local network which is no internet access they have only access to server computer. I need to publish the application to the server computer which others should access through file share or something else. Most of the computers are have Windows XP.

Main question is how should I publish the application through ClikcOnce.

Please if you have some infomartion or example that can help me type it down.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can use the Publish section of the project properties to publish the application through ClickOnce. Then you can choose to publish it to a folder and assuming it will be a network share, you can specify it in the form

```
\\ShareServer\Folder\Subfolder
```